# How come disassemblies for x86 show registers for the x64 platform?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, disassembly

The code below has undefined behavior. That's the reason why I was trying to see the assembly (x86) for the code. I was surprised with the presence of registers like `rbp, rsp, rax, rdi` instead of `ebp, esp, eax` and `edi` for clang and [gcc](https://goo.gl/93a74b). For example, when I look at the disassembly, while debugging this snippet in VS2015, I don't see any register starting with `r` when I'm compiling for the x86 platform.

```
#include <iostream>
void f(int i, int j) { std::cout << i + j << '\n'; }
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    f(i = -1, i = -1000);
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That site compiles for 64 bit by default. You need to enter `-m32` in the options box.

Comment: If you see 64bit registers you're obviously not compiling for 32bit code. And just because you use a 32bit compiler doesn't mean it can't generate 64bit code.

Comment: @jester great!!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have not shown any compilation options, assembly code or anything that would give any hint about what's happening. But x86 code cannot have x64 registers.

Comment: That site uses the compiler you choose, you just need to read the documentation for that version of the compiler to see the options available.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I've just realized this. That's why I erased my prior comment. Thanks.

Comment: some of the instructions are not 16/32/64 specific, when it was a 16bit processor they affected the whole 16 bit register, when 32 then the same instruction affected the whole 32 bit register and now for 64 bit.  so for those the 64 bit register name is not necessarily incorrect and/or you have to know what you are running on to know which is correct

Comment: @Jester Is there any reason why `clang` doesn't accept the option `-m32`?

Comment: Broken installation. Note that clang does accept it, but the 32 bit c++ environment seems to be missing. A simple test program without iostream compiles fine. Also the versions 3.3 and 3.4.1 work there.

Answer (score -2):

This question has been answered in the comments by Jester:

It was disassembled assuming that the code was for an x64 when in fact the code was for an x86 which apparently requires the -m32 switch for this disassembler.

Comment: No, that is not what the comment says.

Comment: godbolt.org shows compiler asm output, not disassembly.  Compilers on godbolt are *compiling for* `-m64` by default, because that's normal.  They're not getting disassembled wrong, the OP is just looking at correct 64bit output.